# Disabling direct access to images using .htaccess

Tags: uploads, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have installed Wordpress in a subdirectory of a subdomain. I am using the following rewrite rule to direct all urls to this subdirectory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysubdomain.mydomain\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1 [L]
```

This is working fine!
Now, I want to only allow logged in users to be able to access the 'wp-content/uploads/' folder. I am using the solution explained here: https://gist.github.com/hakre/1552239

I have added the following rewrite rule to my .htaccess (above the previous rewrite rule):

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This, however, only works for 50%. When I am logged in and I try to access an image with a path like '.../wp-contents/uploads/image.jpg', I get redirected to the log-in page. Just as how it should happen. However, since I installed Wordpress in a subdirectory, the image path actually is '.../wp/wp-contents/uploads/image.jpg'. When I am not logged in and try to access an image with this path, the image opens normally. I am not being redirected to the log-in page.

I have tried adding 'wp' to a rewrite rule, like:

```
RewriteRule ^wp/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But to no success. I am sure I am missing something in my .htaccess file. Any ideas how to ensure that images are no longer accessible for non logged-in users would be much appreciated.

Comment: What other directives do you have in the root `.htaccess` file? Presumably you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/wp` subdirectory? Please include the contents of this `.htaccess` file also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> I have added the following rewrite rule to my .htaccess (above the previous rewrite rule):
>
> RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

You presumably have another `.htaccess` file in the `/wp` subdirectory that contains the main WordPress directives (ie. `# BEGIN WordPress` etc.).

You should be adding the above rule to the `/wp/.htaccess` file, not the one in the root.

When accessing a URL of the form `/wp/...` the mod_rewrite directives in the root `.htaccess` file are completely overridden by the mod_rewrite directives in `/wp/.htaccess` (by default). The mod_rewrite directives in the root `.htaccess` file are not even processed, since mod_rewrite directives are not *inherited* by default.

The `dl-file.php` script should then be in the root of the WordPress installation, not in the document root.

---

*Aside:*

> However, since I installed Wordpress in a subdirectory, the image path actually is `.../wp/wp-contents/uploads/image.jpg`.

Although this would imply you have a mismatch of URLs... some containing the `/wp` subdirectory and some (your static assets) not.

The first rule you posted rewrites requests to the `/wp` subdirectory for any request where it is omitted. (The `.htaccess` file in the `/wp` subdirectory ensures it does not rewrite requests that already contain `/wp`.)

You should either:

- Include `/wp` in *all* your URLs
- Omit `/wp` from *all* your URLs.

You currently appear to have a mixture of both.

Comment: Thanks. I was applying all rewrite rules to the htaccess in root folder. Putting it in the wordpress directory worked like a charme. Sometimes it can be so easy... 
Regarding your second remark: all urls contain '/wp', there is no mixture with/without '/wp'. while testing I noticed the dl-file.php only worked when leaving out '/wp', but when included, it didn't. Should have made this more clear.

Comment: @jc100 You're welcome. When accessing a URL of the form `/wp/...` then the mod_rewrite directives in the root `.htaccess` file are completely overridden (by default). "all urls contain '/wp'" - in that case, your initial rule that "direct(s) all urls to this subdirectory" is not required? (If anything, this should instead be a "redirect", not an internal "rewrite".)